# How long will the Google Contacts API be supported, and is the Google People API the intended replacement?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

At the moment, the People API does not retrieve all the contacts that the Contacts API did, but is suggested as a replacement. If I wanted the old list that included Most Contacted and Other Contacts, I believe I would need the Contacts API. How long is this API intended to be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, People API will replace the Contacts API.

> The new People API uses the newest protocols and technologies and will eventually replace the Contacts API which uses the GData protocol.
>
> [Announcing the People API](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/announcing-people-api.html)

The Contacts API has not been deprecated yet so we don't know how long it will be around. Once Google deprecates an API it is typically available for 1-3 years before being fully shut down.

Comment: It seems odd that this is the official replacement without a clear way to view Most Contacted or Other Contacts.

Comment: "will eventually replace" is probably the key part. It has some features the Contacts API doesn't have and the Contacts API has some features the People API doesn't have.

Comment: My biggest beef with the API is that it is read-only. What should I use to *create* a contact?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is still being supported. Based on the [Google Contacts v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/), that if you only want for read-only access to users' contacts, then that is the time you need to use the People API. It is not stated here that the Contacts API v3 will be deprecated and will stop the supporting here.

Also based on the [Google Contacts API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/terms), after April 20, 2015, the Deprecation Policy in Contacts API will not apply.

Comment: FYI: Contacts API supports readonly access. See: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20